# How to write the correct unit test for Apache Flink data stream, which uses window operator?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I know that there is similar topic here: [Flink Unit Test over ProcessWindowFunction<IN, OUT, KEY, W>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63401125/flink-unit-test-over-processwindowfunctionin-out-key-w), but it does not solve my problem.

Here's my problem:

I'm trying to write a unit test, which is testing Apache Flink pipeline with data stream with `window` operator.

I have the following code:

```java
inputStream
    .keyBy(Event::getSessionId)
    .window(SlidingProcessingTimeWindows.of(
            Time.milliseconds(2000),
            Time.milliseconds(200)
    ))
    .process(new ProcessWindowFunction<Event, Feature, Long, TimeWindow>() {
        @Override
        public void process(Long aLong, Context context, Iterable<Event> elements, Collector<Feature> out) {
            // process window of events here
            out.collect(Feature.newBuilder().build());
        }
    });
```

and I'm testing it like this:

```java
    @Test
    public void shouldRunPipeline() throws Exception {
        long sessionId = 1;
        long userId = 1;

        List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();

        events.add(createAccEvent(sessionId, userId, createTsNow(), 1f, 2f, 3f));
        events.add(createAccEvent(sessionId, userId, createTsNow(), 4f, 5f, 6f));
        events.add(createGyroEvent(sessionId, userId, createTsNow(), 7f, 8f, 9f));
        events.add(createGyroEvent(sessionId, userId, createTsNow(), 10f, 11f, 12f));

        events.add(createTouchDownEvent(sessionId, userId, createTsNow()));

        events.add(createAccEvent(sessionId, userId, createTsNow(), 1f, 2f, 3f));
        events.add(createAccEvent(sessionId, userId, createTsNow(), 4f, 5f, 6f));
        events.add(createGyroEvent(sessionId, userId, createTsNow(), 7f, 8f, 9f));
        events.add(createGyroEvent(sessionId, userId, createTsNow(), 10f, 11f, 12f));

        events.add(createTouchUpEvent(sessionId, userId, createTsNow()));

        events.add(createAccEvent(sessionId, userId, createTsNow(), 1f, 2f, 3f));
        events.add(createAccEvent(sessionId, userId, createTsNow(), 4f, 5f, 6f));
        events.add(createGyroEvent(sessionId, userId, createTsNow(), 7f, 8f, 9f));
        events.add(createGyroEvent(sessionId, userId, createTsNow(), 10f, 11f, 12f));

        CollectSink.values.clear();

        DataStream<Event> source = getTestEnv()
                .fromCollection(events)
                .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(WatermarkStrategy.forMonotonousTimestamps());

        getPipeline()
                .process(source)
                .addSink(new CollectSink());

        getTestEnv().execute();

        List<Feature> features = CollectSink.values;

        assertThat(features).isNotEmpty();
    }

    private long createTsNow() {
        return Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
    }

    private static class CollectSink implements SinkFunction<Feature> {

        public static final List<Feature> values = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

        @Override
        public void invoke(Feature value, Context context) {
            values.add(value);
        }
    }
```

Method `getPipeline()` is creating my pipeline, `getTestEnv()` is getting test environment from the base testing class, and methods with names `createXEvent()` are my helper methods for creating events for the input stream for test.

I used Sink in the test because I read somewhere that `DataStreamUtils.collect()` may not work with `window` operator because data is accumulated in the different way in such case.

I run this test in the debugger and `ProcessWindowFunction` is **never reached**!

Once I remove `window` operator, `ProcessFunction` (this time `KeyedProcessFunction`) is reached. This example is shown on the snippet below.

```java
inputStream
    .keyBy(Event::getSessionId)
    .process(new KeyedProcessFunction<Long, Event, Feature>() {
        @Override
        public void processElement(Event value, Context ctx, Collector<Feature> out) {
            // process events here
            out.collect(Feature.newBuilder().build());

        }
    });
```

My question is: How to write correct unit test for the stream, which uses `window` operator, so the instance of `ProcessWindowFunction` in the `process` method will be reached?

I could not find any valid solution to this problem in the Apache Flink documentation and on the web.

I'm able to unit test logic of the process function separately, but I'd like to unit test whole pipeline too.

I will appreciate any help.

Regards,

Piotr

Comment: It looks strange for me when you use `SlidingProcessingTimeWindows` and assign watermarks to the events. Is it not the case to use `SlidingEventTimeWindows`?

Comment: I'm not sure. Nevertheless, when I remove this assignment, effect is the same (process function is not invoked and there is no data on the output).

Comment: Writing just FYI: I ended up testing process just function instead of the whole pipeline/stream using pure java testing methods like JUnit and assertion libraries.